# vs code: is it possible to fix the size of the editor windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a dual screen setup and would like to have a fixed number of editor windows with a fixed size open to avoid that an editor window bridges between two screens. VS code adapts editor windows automatically as they open and close.

I found a hint to `.tab.sizing-fixed` but I cannot find it in the settings (in 1.32). The `"workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink"` seems to handle only the sizing of the tabs, not the editor window.

Comment: Have you look into vs code (User and Workspace Settings) Documentation?
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: yes, I did but could not find a entry for fixing the editor width. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: An "editor" in vscode is each individual file tab, not the whole vscode window.  Which are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

centered layout auto resize off, if that would work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).